# Swift 4 - querying facebook with FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, facebook

I try to create a function for querying the Facebook database. Unfortunately, the syntax changed with the last version of swift. Maybe someone can post me the solution ?

Thx.

[Func donneesFB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMTDy.png)

Comment: It's a lot easier to help you if you post your code as text instead of in an image.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to help you if you post your code as text instead of in an image.

Two things that will likely help you out here:

First, cast your result to the type of dictionary you are expecting before trying to access it:

```
guard let resultDict = result as? [String:Any] else { return }
```

You should now be able to use it like you tried to:

```
let nom = resultDict["name"] as? String
```

Secondly, for the error on your first line, simply get rid of the argument labels, `nom`, `prenom` and so on, leaving just the types.

Comment: okay it's fine. But i've a problem with a variable (let photo).

let photo = result["picture"]!["data"]!!["url"] as? String

I've the error : "Type 'Any' has no subscript members". Any ideas ?

Comment: This is likely the same error you had before but now on a deeper level of your result dictionary. Assuming you've used the first line I gave you above, the compiler now knows that result is a `[String:Any]`. So that means that if you try and get `result["picture"]`, the compiler will think that's an object of type `Any`. It's up to you to continue casting in the same way as I showed you in my first line all the way down to `"url"`. To get you started: `if let picture = result["picture"] as [String: String] { }`. I am assuming here that "data" is a string.